# Facebook v4.0 php sdk on v2.0 api high res pictures

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Previously using the Facebook php sdk when I called a feed like 'me/home' or 'me/feed', I was able to check if a post contained an object_id for a photo, and if it did I could call '/{object_id}?fields=images' to get a high resolution picture of the photo.

This seemed to have stopped working. Does anyone know if there is a way to get high resolution pictures from a newsfeed using the facebook api?